# How would I make an auto redirect for site maintenance?

Tags: php, html

I have made a maintenance page for my forums website but I need to add an auto redirect like say when the site is off maintenance mode how would I make then auto redirect them back to the index? - Sorry if this isn't that clear but it's hard to explain to me

Comment: You can do that with `.htaccess` or, if you have core file you use everywhere, then redirect by writing redirection script in that file.

Comment: Thanks, but like what would I put in .htaccess? I know how to do redirects in .htaccess but I don't know how to do that type of redirect @EdvinTenovimas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set redirect header: `header('Location: redirect_url');`, it can be controled by some global variable and if statment:

```
$is_maintenance = true;
...
if($is_maintenance) header('Location: redirect_url');
```

Comment: @RoxanneMitchell glad that i can help, please mark answer as accepted if it solve your problem :)

Comment: I don't think Roxanne knows how to do it so I'm upvoting instead. :)